# Deploy the bitbucket code directly on production server

Tags: php, laravel, server, ftp, bitbucket

I am using the `bitbucket` to store our project. Now the problem is the project is very large and having `more then 20k files` in it. My server having `FTP connection` so i am not able to copy and paste the complete project code on server. So i want to direct deploy my code from bitbucket to my production server.

I can connect to the bitbucket server and make a `git pull` but i really want to find something to `automate` this.

I am looking for a easy and fast solution but i did not find anything for bitbucket, all solution seems to be designed for github...

Any `service` or `tool` for that to automate this process ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few way to do this i tend to follow and [adapt this Turotial](http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2013/11/19/automated-git-deployments-from-bitbucket/)

This works by using the BitBucket Webhooks a couple of things to note

1) git security is daft the user that creates the repo normally is the only one who can affect it so you will have to make sure your apache user or group (in the case of Ubuntu Server www-data:www-data) has the abillity to use the git repo (by use i mean it needs to be able to pull/checkout/commit)

2)your web server will have to be online for the auto deployment to work

3)your web hook receive file will be over righting your site make sure it secure you could do this with .htpasswd setup. if you use .htpasswd setup in in BitBucket when you setup your webhook you can use them inside the url E.G `http://<username>:<passwd>@yourdomain.com/path/to/deployment.php`

But your webhook php file should look something like:

```
<?php
$repo_dir = '/home/<username>/<repo-name>.git';
$web_root_dir = '/home/<username>/www';

// Full path to git binary is required if git is not in your PHP user's path. Otherwise just use 'git'.
$git_bin_path = 'git';

$update = false;

// Parse data from Bitbucket hook payload
$payload = json_decode($_POST['payload']);

if (empty($payload->commits)){
  // When merging and pushing to bitbucket, the commits array will be empty.
  // In this case there is no way to know what branch was pushed to, so we will do an update.
  $update = true;
} else {
  foreach ($payload->commits as $commit) {
    $branch = $commit->branch;
    if ($branch === 'production' || isset($commit->branches) && in_array('production', $commit->branches)) {
      $update = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}

if ($update) {
  // Do a git checkout to the web root
  exec('cd ' . $repo_dir . ' && ' . $git_bin_path  . ' fetch');
  exec('cd ' . $repo_dir . ' && GIT_WORK_TREE=' . $web_root_dir . ' ' . $git_bin_path  . ' checkout -f');

  // Log the deployment
  $commit_hash = shell_exec('cd ' . $repo_dir . ' && ' . $git_bin_path  . ' rev-parse --short HEAD');
  file_put_contents('deploy.log', date('m/d/Y h:i:s a') . " Deployed branch: " .  $branch . " Commit: " . $commit_hash . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
```

Make sure it in the public html directory and it is not loaded by Larvel it should be a raw access php file.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the Bitbucket documentation. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/migrating-bitbucket-server-to-another-server-776640406.html

Answer (score 0):

Laravel forge works great for deploying code from git to production. It also handels server configuration and server setup.